# NGINX - ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS ao reescrever regras htaccess

Tags: htaccess, apache, docker, nginx, mod-rewrite

estou tentando converter umas regras do htaccess para o NGINX e estou obtendo o ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

O código do htaccess é este https://pastebin.com/UwGnNybj

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

# Secuirty Control
<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|log|sh|inc|bak|tpl)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# Cache Control
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|css|js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# Gzip Control
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/jpg
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/png
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L,QSA]

# Installer
RewriteRule ^install/?$ install.php [L,QSA]

# Static Pages
RewriteRule ^static/([^/]+)/?$ static.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]

# Contacts
RewriteRule ^contacts/?$ contact.php [L,QSA]

# Directory
RewriteRule ^directory/?$ directory.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^directory/([^/]+)/?$ directory.php?view=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^directory/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ directory.php?view=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]

# Search
RewriteRule ^search/?$ search.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^search/hashtag/([^/]+)/?$ search.php?query=$1&hashtag=1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/?$ search.php?query=$1&hashtag=0 [L,QSA]

# Sign(in|up|out)
RewriteRule ^signin/?$ sign.php?do=in [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^signup/?$ sign.php?do=up [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^signout/?$ sign.php?do=out [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^reset/?$ sign.php?do=reset [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^activation/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ activation.php?id=$1&token=$2 [L,QSA]

# Social Logins
RewriteRule ^connect/([^/]+)/?$ connect.php?do=connect&provider=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^revoke/([^/]+)/?$ connect.php?do=revoke&provider=$1 [L,QSA]

# Packages
RewriteRule ^packages/?$ packages.php [L,QSA]

# Started
RewriteRule ^started/?$ started.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^started/finished?$ started.php?finished=true [L,QSA]

# Messages
RewriteRule ^messages/?$ messages.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^messages/new?$ messages.php?view=new [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^messages/([^/]+)/?$ messages.php?cid=$1 [L,QSA]

# Notifications
RewriteRule ^notifications/?$ notifications.php [L,QSA]

# Settings
RewriteRule ^settings/?$ settings.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^settings/([^/]+)/?$ settings.php?view=$1 [L,QSA]

# Posts & Photos
RewriteRule ^posts/([^/]+)/?$ post.php?post_id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^photos/([^/]+)/?$ photo.php?photo_id=$1 [L,QSA]

# Saved
RewriteRule ^saved/?$ index.php?view=saved [L,QSA]

# Ads
RewriteRule ^ads/?$ ads.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^ads/new?$ ads.php?view=new [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^ads/edit/([^/]+)/?$ ads.php?view=edit&campaign_id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^wallet/?$ ads.php?view=wallet [L,QSA]

# Boosted
RewriteRule ^boosted/posts/?$ index.php?view=boosted_posts [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^boosted/pages/?$ index.php?view=boosted_pages [L,QSA]

# People
RewriteRule ^people/?$ people.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^people/find/?$ people.php?view=find [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^people/friend_requests/?$ people.php?view=friend_requests [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^people/sent_requests/?$ people.php?view=sent_requests [L,QSA]

# Pages
RewriteRule ^pages/?$ pages.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^pages/liked/?$ pages.php?view=liked [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^pages/manage/?$ pages.php?view=manage [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^pages/([^/]+)/?$ page.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^pages/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ page.php?username=$1&view=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^pages/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ page.php?username=$1&view=$2&id=$3 [L,QSA]

# Groups
RewriteRule ^groups/?$ groups.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^groups/joined/?$ groups.php?view=joined [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^groups/manage/?$ groups.php?view=manage [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^groups/([^/]+)/?$ group.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^groups/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ group.php?username=$1&view=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^groups/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ group.php?username=$1&view=$2&id=$3 [L,QSA]

# Events
RewriteRule ^events/?$ events.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^events/going/?$ events.php?view=going [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^events/interested/?$ events.php?view=interested [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^events/invited/?$ events.php?view=invited [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^events/manage/?$ events.php?view=manage [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^events/([^/]+)/?$ event.php?event_id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^events/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ event.php?event_id=$1&view=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^events/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ event.php?event_id=$1&view=$2&id=$3 [L,QSA]

# Forums
RewriteRule ^forums/?$ forums.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^forums/my-threads/?$ forums.php?view=my-threads [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^forums/my-replies/?$ forums.php?view=my-replies [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^forums/search/?$ forums.php?view=search [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^forums/search-results/?$ forums.php?view=search-results [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^forums/new-thread/([^/]+)/?$ forums.php?view=new-thread&forum_id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^forums/edit-thread/([^/]+)/?$ forums.php?view=edit-thread&thread_id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^forums/new-reply/([^/]+)/?$ forums.php?view=new-reply&thread_id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^forums/edit-reply/([^/]+)/?$ forums.php?view=edit-reply&reply_id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^forums/thread/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ forums.php?view=thread&thread_id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^forums/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ forums.php?view=forum&forum_id=$1 [L,QSA]

# Blogs
RewriteRule ^articles/?$ index.php?view=articles [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^blogs/?$ blogs.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^blogs/new/?$ blogs.php?view=new [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^blogs/edit/([^/]+)/?$ blogs.php?view=edit&post_id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^blogs/category/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ blogs.php?view=category&category_id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^blogs/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ blogs.php?view=article&post_id=$1 [L,QSA]

# Market
RewriteRule ^products/?$ index.php?view=products [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^market/?$ market.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^market/search/?$ market.php?view=search [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^market/search/([^/]+)/?$ market.php?view=search&query=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^market/search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ market.php?view=search&query=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^market/category/([^/]+)/?$ market.php?view=category&category_id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^market/category/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ market.php?view=category&category_id=$1&category_url=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^market/category/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ market.php?view=category&category_id=$1&category_url=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^market/([^/]+)/?$ market.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]

# Games
RewriteRule ^games/?$ games.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^games/played/?$ games.php?view=played [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^games/([^/]+)/?$ game.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

# Admin Panel
RewriteRule ^admincp/?$ admin.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^admincp/([^/]+)/?$ admin.php?view=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^admincp/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ admin.php?view=$1&sub_view=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^admincp/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ admin.php?view=$1&sub_view=$2&id=$3 [L,QSA]

# Profile
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1&view=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1&view=$2&id=$3 [L,QSA]
```

O código que eu converti usando o https://winginx.com/en/htaccess e o código que implementei no meu container docker é este https://pastebin.com/y1qMEzUw

```
server {
    index index.php;
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /code-admin;

    location / {
      if (-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^/install/?$ /install.php last;
      }
      rewrite ^/([^/]+)/?$ /profile.php?username=$1 last;
      rewrite ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /profile.php?username=$1&view=$2 last;
      rewrite ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /profile.php?username=$1&view=$2&id=$3 last;
    }

    location /static {
      rewrite ^/static/([^/]+)/?$ /static.php?url=$1 last;
    }

    location /contacts {
      rewrite ^/contacts/?$ /contact.php last;
    }

    location /directory {
      rewrite ^/directory/?$ /directory.php last;
      rewrite ^/directory/([^/]+)/?$ /directory.php?view=$1 last;
      rewrite ^/directory/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /directory.php?view=$1&page=$2 last;
    }

    location /search {
      rewrite ^/search/?$ /search.php last;
      rewrite ^/search/hashtag/([^/]+)/?$ /search.php?query=$1&hashtag=1 last;
      rewrite ^/search/([^/]+)/?$ /search.php?query=$1&hashtag=0 last;
    }

    location /signin {
      rewrite ^/signin/?$ /sign.php?do=in last;
    }

    location /signup {
      rewrite ^/signup/?$ /sign.php?do=up last;
    }

    location /signout {
      rewrite ^/signout/?$ /sign.php?do=out last;
    }

    location /reset {
      rewrite ^/reset/?$ /sign.php?do=reset last;
    }

    location /activation {
      rewrite ^/activation/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /activation.php?id=$1&token=$2 last;
    }

    location /connect {
      rewrite ^/connect/([^/]+)/?$ /connect.php?do=connect&provider=$1 last;
    }

    location /revoke {
      rewrite ^/revoke/([^/]+)/?$ /connect.php?do=revoke&provider=$1 last;
    }

    location /packages {
      rewrite ^/packages/?$ /packages.php last;
    }

    location /started {
      rewrite ^/started/?$ /started.php last;
      rewrite ^/started/finished?$ /started.php?finished=true last;
    }

    location /messages {
      rewrite ^/messages/?$ /messages.php last;
      rewrite ^/messages/new?$ /messages.php?view=new last;
      rewrite ^/messages/([^/]+)/?$ /messages.php?cid=$1 last;
    }

    location /notifications {
      rewrite ^/notifications/?$ /notifications.php last;
    }

    location /settings {
      rewrite ^/settings/?$ /settings.php last;
      rewrite ^/settings/([^/]+)/?$ /settings.php?view=$1 last;
    }

    location /posts {
      rewrite ^/posts/([^/]+)/?$ /post.php?post_id=$1 last;
    }

    location /photos {
      rewrite ^/photos/([^/]+)/?$ /photo.php?photo_id=$1 last;
    }

    location /saved {
      rewrite ^/saved/?$ /index.php?view=saved last;
    }

    location /ads {
      rewrite ^/ads/?$ /ads.php last;
      rewrite ^/ads/new?$ /ads.php?view=new last;
      rewrite ^/ads/edit/([^/]+)/?$ /ads.php?view=edit&campaign_id=$1 last;
    }

    location /wallet {
      rewrite ^/wallet/?$ /ads.php?view=wallet last;
    }

    location /boosted {
      rewrite ^/boosted/posts/?$ /index.php?view=boosted_posts last;
      rewrite ^/boosted/pages/?$ /index.php?view=boosted_pages last;
    }

    location /people {
      rewrite ^/people/?$ /people.php last;
      rewrite ^/people/find/?$ /people.php?view=find last;
      rewrite ^/people/friend_requests/?$ /people.php?view=friend_requests last;
      rewrite ^/people/sent_requests/?$ /people.php?view=sent_requests last;
    }

    location /pages {
      rewrite ^/pages/?$ /pages.php last;
      rewrite ^/pages/liked/?$ /pages.php?view=liked last;
      rewrite ^/pages/manage/?$ /pages.php?view=manage last;
      rewrite ^/pages/([^/]+)/?$ /page.php?username=$1 last;
      rewrite ^/pages/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /page.php?username=$1&view=$2 last;
      rewrite ^/pages/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /page.php?username=$1&view=$2&id=$3 last;
    }

    location /groups {
      rewrite ^/groups/?$ /groups.php last;
      rewrite ^/groups/joined/?$ /groups.php?view=joined last;
      rewrite ^/groups/manage/?$ /groups.php?view=manage last;
      rewrite ^/groups/([^/]+)/?$ /group.php?username=$1 last;
      rewrite ^/groups/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /group.php?username=$1&view=$2 last;
      rewrite ^/groups/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /group.php?username=$1&view=$2&id=$3 last;
    }

    location /events {
      rewrite ^/events/?$ /events.php last;
      rewrite ^/events/going/?$ /events.php?view=going last;
      rewrite ^/events/interested/?$ /events.php?view=interested last;
      rewrite ^/events/invited/?$ /events.php?view=invited last;
      rewrite ^/events/manage/?$ /events.php?view=manage last;
      rewrite ^/events/([^/]+)/?$ /event.php?event_id=$1 last;
      rewrite ^/events/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /event.php?event_id=$1&view=$2 last;
      rewrite ^/events/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /event.php?event_id=$1&view=$2&id=$3 last;
    }

    location /forums {
      rewrite ^/forums/?$ /forums.php last;
      rewrite ^/forums/my-threads/?$ /forums.php?view=my-threads last;
      rewrite ^/forums/my-replies/?$ /forums.php?view=my-replies last;
      rewrite ^/forums/search/?$ /forums.php?view=search last;
      rewrite ^/forums/search-results/?$ /forums.php?view=search-results last;
      rewrite ^/forums/new-thread/([^/]+)/?$ /forums.php?view=new-thread&forum_id=$1 last;
      rewrite ^/forums/edit-thread/([^/]+)/?$ /forums.php?view=edit-thread&thread_id=$1 last;
      rewrite ^/forums/new-reply/([^/]+)/?$ /forums.php?view=new-reply&thread_id=$1 last;
      rewrite ^/forums/edit-reply/([^/]+)/?$ /forums.php?view=edit-reply&reply_id=$1 last;
      rewrite ^/forums/thread/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /forums.php?view=thread&thread_id=$1 last;
      rewrite ^/forums/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /forums.php?view=forum&forum_id=$1 last;
    }

    location /articles {
      rewrite ^/articles/?$ /index.php?view=articles last;
    }

    location /blogs {
      rewrite ^/blogs/?$ /blogs.php last;
      rewrite ^/blogs/new/?$ /blogs.php?view=new last;
      rewrite ^/blogs/edit/([^/]+)/?$ /blogs.php?view=edit&post_id=$1 last;
      rewrite ^/blogs/category/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /blogs.php?view=category&category_id=$1 last;
      rewrite ^/blogs/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /blogs.php?view=article&post_id=$1 last;
    }

    location /products {
      rewrite ^/products/?$ /index.php?view=products last;
    }

    location /market {
      rewrite ^/market/?$ /market.php last;
      rewrite ^/market/search/?$ /market.php?view=search last;
      rewrite ^/market/search/([^/]+)/?$ /market.php?view=search&query=$1 last;
      rewrite ^/market/search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /market.php?view=search&query=$1&page=$2 last;
      rewrite ^/market/category/([^/]+)/?$ /market.php?view=category&category_id=$1 last;
      rewrite ^/market/category/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /market.php?view=category&category_id=$1&category_url=$2 last;
      rewrite ^/market/category/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /market.php?view=category&category_id=$1&category_url=$2&page=$3 last;
      rewrite ^/market/([^/]+)/?$ /market.php?page=$1 last;
    }

    location /games {
      rewrite ^/games/?$ /games.php last;
      rewrite ^/games/played/?$ /games.php?view=played last;
      rewrite ^/games/([^/]+)/?$ /game.php?id=$1 last;
    }

    location /admincp {
      rewrite ^/admincp/?$ /admin.php last;
      rewrite ^/admincp/([^/]+)/?$ /admin.php?view=$1 last;
      rewrite ^/admincp/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /admin.php?view=$1&sub_view=$2 last;
      rewrite ^/admincp/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /admin.php?view=$1&sub_view=$2&id=$3 last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass php:9000;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }


}
```

Comment: Provavelmente em algum lugar está tendo um loop de redirecionamentos, tipo da url `/foo` para a `/bar` e da `/bar` para a `/foo`, dai da esse erro. Observação, **sempre** coloque o código aqui no site, não apenas em links

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme, coloquei o código incorporado aqui, mas mesmo procurando o que você citou, ainda não encontrei.